# Key repeat X11 xterm & urxvt

Tags: macos, unix, shell, xorg, xterm

I've been trying to get an xmonad development environment setup on my OS X box for a little while right now. I have OS wide key repeating enabled and it's working in other apps, however when I hold down a key it only repeats the character twice then stops. Anyone have ideas on what could be the problem? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Did some more searching and discovered in recent updates the key repeat rate for x in OS X is set at some odd value. Anyway, to whoever else may have this issue, run this in your shell:

```
    xset r rate <milliseconds_before_repeat> <repeats_per_second>
```

Or just `xset r rate` to reset the keyboard repeat rate to default X settings (i.e: something sane.)